# Should I include visiting students in my CV

Tags: teaching, cv, supervision

I am currently a Post-Doc in the field of physics. During the last years, a number of students from different universities (from across the world) were visiting me for short (1 week) or long (3 months) periods.

Since they came to specifically work with me, I was supervising them during that time and now I am wondering if I should include them somehow in my CV (e.g. in the section *Teaching*, listed as *visiting students* or something similar) ?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me, especially if the outcomes were positive.

Comment: Would you just name them in your CV in the respective section or what else would you write (e. g. specific tasks, help, collaboration)?

Comment: My idea was to name them in the respective section and then try to (very briefly) name the project.

Comment: Is this your collaboration project which was the reason for their stay/visit or is it 'just' their research/dissertation project? If you directly collaborated with them, I would put them in the CV and anem what you did (together). Otherwise, it might not be clear for a reader of your CV what this 'visiting student list' exactly means?!

Comment: @Stefan_W good point. It was actually "my" project (or projects where I had a leading positions) or simulation software I had written they were interested in. So I will incorporate that in the description, thanks (I would actually accept that as a valid answer).

Comment: Does "visiting students" mean "interns"? (If so, then this addresses @Stefan_W's issue "_it might not be clear for a reader of your CV what this 'visiting student list' exactly means_." )

Comment: @user2768 no - but good point, hadn't thought of "interns" - "visiting students" was referring to (mostly) PhD-students who were working on projects similar to one of mine and were looking for expertise/guidance

Comment: @Alf, although your institute has called them "visiting students," would another institute call them "interns"? Also, are the visiting students calling themselves interns? From what you've explained, they sound very much like interns. (Noting that the definition of an "intern" is very vague.)

Comment: @user2768 hmm, OK, I see, that seems to be a problem with the definition of "intern" as you said and strongly depends on the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it transparent for future readers that your question got a (preliminary) answer suggestion: 
If you directly collaborated with them, I would put them in the [cv](/questions/tagged/cv) and mention what you did (together). This helps the visiting student, because his/her name is mentioned in relation to you. It also helps you to keep track of your collaboration project and to show others (in future applications) what you did in the last years. As you said, being in contact and supervising students for a certain time can also be seen as a form of [teaching](/questions/tagged/teaching). Perhaps, later you will publish with some of them papers and then, it is interesting to know that your co-author(s) might have been a former visiting student Otherwise, if you just mention their names in the CV, it might not be clear for a reader of your CV what this 'visiting student list' exactly means.